# Linux - openssl sha256 using key from file

Tags: linux, shell, openssl

I have a 32 byte key stored in a file called test_key.key

I wish to use openssl to create hash of a different file called mytext.txt. I need to create the hash using HMAC-SHA-256 & the key in test_key.key

I thought I had it working with the following command:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac $test_key.key mytext.txt
```

However, on closer examination I noticed it was using the string "test_key.key", not the actual file contents. I have tried a few different variations of this for the key file such as:

```
"$test_key.key"
'$test_key.key'
/test_key.key
```

Sadly, they all seem to have the same problem.

Can anyone advise me on this? I wish to keep this as a one line command if possible.

Comment: `openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac $(<test_key.key) mytext.txt`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm surprised that this works, especially if the key contains non printable character. Personally I prefer `openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt "hexkey:$(xxd -ps -c32 test_key.key)" mytext.txt` that is explicit about the key format.

Comment: There are quite few caveats to the general use, but with a sha256 string of `unsigned char` you should be fine (as long as there isn't a `'/* '` or something else that could be interpreted as a independent command) I wouldn't recommend it for much else.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin calling `openssl ... $(<test_key.key) ...` exposes the key in the process info

Answer (score 5):

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac $(<test_key.key) mytext.txt
```

(credit to user David C. Rankin)

Comment: It is helpful to use quotes to avoid issues with special characters (couldn't edit because edits must have 6 chars): openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$(<test_key.key)" mytext.txt